# How do I calculate beforehand how much memory calloc would allocate?

Tags: c, calloc

I basically have this piece of code.

```
char (* text)[1][80];
text = calloc(2821522,80);
```

The way I calculated it, that calloc should have allocated 215.265045 megabytes of RAM, however, the program in the end exceeded that number and allocated nearly 700mb of ram.

So it appears I cannot properly know how much memory that function will allocate.

How does one calculate that propery?

Comment: Can you post the full program?

Comment: The `calloc()` call itself should have allocated the calculated amount, or only slightly more (or failed).

How do you know that your program 700 megabytes?  How do you know that it was the `calloc()` call that caused it to do so?  What happens if you run a program that just calls `calloc()` with those arguments and does nothing else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`calloc` (and `malloc` for that matter) is free to allocate as much space as it needs to satisfy the request.

So, no, you cannot tell in advance how much it will *actually* give you, you can only assume that it's given you the amount you asked for.

Having said that, 700M seems a little excessive so I'd be investigating whether the `calloc` was solely responsible for that by, for example, a program that *only* does the `calloc` and nothing more.

You might also want to investigate how you're *measuring* that memory usage.

For example, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (void) {
    char (* text)[1][80];
    struct mallinfo mi;

    mi = mallinfo(); printf ("%d\n", mi.uordblks);
    text = calloc(2821522,80);
    mi = mallinfo(); printf ("%d\n", mi.uordblks);

    return 0;
}
```

outputs, on my system:

```
66144
225903256
```

meaning that the `calloc` has allocated `225,837,112` bytes which is only a smidgeon (`115,352` bytes or `0.05%`) above the requested `225,721,760`.

Comment: I am on Windows. I looked at the Task Manager, and the program was at 680 megabytes. But thanks, I will investigate without just a call.

Comment: @farmdve: first, what is it at _without_ the `calloc`? You need the difference, not the size. Secondly, Task Manager presents a fairly simplified view of memory usage which is not directly related to the memory arena. You probably want to sneak over to sysinternals and get your hands on Process Explorer and VMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the underlying implementation of malloc/calloc.

It generally works like this - there's this thing called the heap pointer which points to the top of the heap - the area from where dynamic memory gets allocated. When memory is first allocated, malloc internally requests x amount of memory from the kernel - i.e. the heap pointer increments by a certain amount to make that space available. That x may or may not be equal to the size of the memory block you requested (it might be larger to account for future mallocs). If it isn't, then you're given at least the amount of memory you requested(sometimes you're given more memory because of alignment issues). The rest is made part of an internal free list maintained by malloc. To sum it up malloc has some underlying data structures and a lot depends on how they are implemented.

My guess is that the x amount of memory was larger (for whatever reason) than you requested and hence malloc/calloc was holding on to the rest in its free list. Try allocating some more memory and see if the footprint increases.